# How can I ask Bazel to rerun a cached test?

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to analyze and fix a flaky test which is often green.
My problem is that once the test passes Bazel doesn't re-run it until any of the inputs have changed.
I saw you can ask Bazel to re-run a target but AFAICT it's only until the first time it's green (i.e. to mitigate a flaky test and not solve it).

Is there a way to ask Bazel to run the test even if it passed?
I'd like something like `bazel test --force-attempts=50 //my-package:my-target`

Comment: `bazel test --cache_test_results=no ...`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In addition to [`--cache_test_results`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--cache_test_results), Bazel actually has a flag specifically designed for diagnosing flaky tests: [`--runs_per_test`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--runs_per_test), which will rerun a test N times and only keep logs from the failing runs:

```
$ bazel test --runs_per_test=10 :flaker
INFO: Found 1 test target...
FAIL: //:flaker (run 10 of 10) (see /output/testlogs/flaker/test_run_10_of_10.log).
FAIL: //:flaker (run 4 of 10) (see /output/testlogs/flaker/test_run_4_of_10.log).
FAIL: //:flaker (run 5 of 10) (see /output/testlogs/flaker/test_run_5_of_10.log).
FAIL: //:flaker (run 9 of 10) (see /output/testlogs/flaker/test_run_9_of_10.log).
FAIL: //:flaker (run 3 of 10) (see /output/testlogs/flaker/test_run_3_of_10.log).
Target //:flaker up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/flaker
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.828s, Critical Path: 0.42s
//:flaker                                                                FAILED
 
Executed 1 out of 1 tests: 1 fails locally.
```

You can use it to quickly figure out how flaky a test is and get some failing logs.

Comment: One catch with `--runs_per_test` is that bazel runs the tests in parallel. This may not be desirable if the test is accessing a global structure e.g the file system and a proper synchronization is not available.

Comment: You can pass `--local_test_jobs=1` if you want to use `--runs_per_test` but not in parallel.

Answer (score 74):

There's a flag for it

> ```
> --cache_test_results=(yes|no|auto) (-t)
> ```

> If this option is set to 'auto' (the default) then Bazel will only rerun a test if any of the following conditions applies:

> - Bazel detects changes in the test or its dependencies
> - the test is marked as `external`
> - multiple test runs were requested with `--runs_per_test`
> - the test failed

> If 'no', all tests will be executed unconditionally.

> If 'yes', the caching behavior will be the same as auto except that it may cache test failures and test runs with `--runs_per_test`.

> Note that test results are always saved in Bazel's output tree, regardless of whether this option is enabled, so you needn't have used `--cache_test_results` on the prior run(s) of `bazel test` in order to get cache hits. The option only affects whether Bazel will use previously saved results, not whether it will save results of the current run.

> Users who have enabled this option by default in their `.bazelrc` file may find the abbreviations `-t` (on) or `-t-` (off) convenient for overriding the default on a particular run.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--cache_test_results

Comment: `--cache_test_results=no`